# Database Vender Error 245

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

My code generates this error message. How can I correct this?

[image: Error message]

```
Rpt.Bills_Per_Month Rpt = new Rpt.Bills_Per_Month();
Rpt.SetParameterValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
Rpt.Rpt frm = new Rpt.Rpt();
frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Rpt;
frm.ShowDialog();
ALTER proc [dbo].[month_bills] 
@Date nvarchar(20) 
AS  
SELECT * from Pay_Bills 
WHERE ((DATEPART(MM, Date_of_Pay) = @Date) AND (DATEPART(YY, Date_of_Pay) = @Date))
```

Comment: How could you @Date parameter be both a MM and an YY from the field Date_Of_Pay?

Comment: Opps sorry i just still beginner
i make two parameters and it works well thanks